# Opening a python file with argument from another file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to open the CapGenVoice.py from another file using arguments but every time getting error as

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'image' referenced before assignment

this is my code

```
import subprocess
loc = r"C:\Users\Ajax\New\a.jpg"
subprocess.call("python CapGenVoice.py -i loc", shell=True)
```

this is `CapGenVoice.py`

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument('-i', '--image', required=True, help="Image Path")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
img_path = args['image']
```

Comment: There is a space in the attachment name. Put it as a single string. And also the path is not escaped completely. Could you try changing those and run?

Comment: I tried changing the file name but its showing the same error

Comment: Any particular reason you don't make `CapGenVoice` provide a function to import and use?

Comment: @tobias_k yes actually the CapGenVoice have to be in a different file

Comment: Can you post code after update ?

Comment: @T.kowshikYedida updated

Comment: Ok. Can you try removing capgenvoice import? According to your code, we don't need an import. Unless we see capgenvoice we can't say exactly.

Comment: @T.kowshikYedida `CapGenVoice.py` code uploded

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have made a minor mistake by including `loc` as a string in the subprocess command instead of a variable. Because of that, the script was looking for a file called `loc` instead of `C:\Users\Ajax\New\a.jpg`

Here is the correct code:

```py
import CapGenVoice
import subprocess
loc = r"C:\Users\Ajax\New\a.jpg"
subprocess.call(f"python CapGenVoice.py -i '{loc}'", shell=True)
```

Comment: no the same error is coming

Comment: @Ajax It's odd that you are getting the same error. I updated the code by putting single quotes around the `loc` variable. Can you try running the updated code and let me know what error you are getting?

Comment: `fileUpload.py: error: the following arguments are required: -i/--image` i tried with single quote and curly brackets

Comment: `subprocess.call("python CapGenVoice.py -i %s" % loc, shell=True)` try this one do get same error ?

Comment: @Sinakzlca now its showing `IndentationError: expected an indented block`

Comment: can you put part of CapGenVoice.py that gets argument?

Comment: @Sinakzlca I updated the question, now I'm getting `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'image' referenced before assignment` error

Comment: make your image variable global (`global image`), also don't forget  fixing format of subprocess.call `(subprocess.call(f"python another.py -i {loc}", shell=True))`